# Swift - Can my code switch threads when calling a function

Tags: swift, methods, thread-safety

In the code below, I have reduced many lines into, what I hope are, the essentials. I'm getting this error:

> UI API called on a background thread

My question is, when I call a method from inside DispatchQueue.main.async, does that method get executed on the main thread as well? I'm doubly confused because, 1) I thought I was on the main thread, and second, I didn't think I was doing anything UI related.

```
//Downloading data on a background thread above this line
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   //Go through all the recently downloaded customers
   for (index, customer) in customers.enumerated() { 
      //for each, add a new customer to core data
      self.createNewCustomer(customer: customer)
   }
}

func createNewCustomer(customer: Customer) {
   let newCustomer = Customers(context: self.context)
   ...
   //Convert time to seconds using a method in a different view controller.
   let seconds = CustomerViewController().secondsFromDate(date: date)
   //Save to core data and repeat
   appDelegate.saveContext()
}
```

Comment: The error should provide a specific line indicating where the problem is. I would strongly suspect `appDelegate` itself (if that's computed) or something inside of `saveContext`. "UI related" includes anything at all talking to `UIApplication`, including asking for the delegate. You generally should not hang random things on UIApplicationDelegate. It doesn't exist as a place to stick "global" code. Its purpose is to assist the UIApplication object.

Comment: Also check the stack. It's very likely that this is not where you're calling `createNewCustomer` from (or this is likely not where you're getting the error from). To the underlying question, yes, all code inside a `.main.async` call will be dispatched to the main queue, which is run exclusively on the main thread. That indicates that this is not how the error is occurring.

Comment: Thanks @Rob Napier - checking the stack pointed me in the right direction. It turned out to be the `secondsFromDate` method in a different controller. When I moved the method in with the rest of the code above everything worked fine. I guess that code existed outside of `.main.async`? One more question - when you say I shouldn't "hang random things on `UIApplicationDelegate`" I assume you mean I shouldn't call `saveContext()` from there? But isn't that how `AppDelegate` is configured when you first start a project with `Core Data` enabled?

Comment: Yes; Apple's templates are horrible, and are designed for getting up and running quickly rather than maintainable code. It's a problem…